# How to create a full width dropdown menu outside a container in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu

How to create a full width dropdown menu outside the nav container?

I want to create a dropdown menu for multiple list items just like [starbucks.nl](http://starbucks.nl) in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6wz7L9ur/1/).

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row ">
...
</ul>

.megamenu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thnx! Exactly what I was looking for